# Bmw 530d moves my car all over road on bumpy roads

Tags: bmw, steering, alignment

I own a bmw 530d and i just met with an accident wherein the car’s right side suspension / arm/ alloy (both front and back only right side) got replaced , i got the suspension and tyre alignment done several times but when on a bumpy road my car does not hold the grip and when in high speed , starts to get out of control pulling itself left or right( no particular direction) ..
The showroom is unable to fig out why and same as other service centres .

Comment: Did they give you the alignment readings?  If so, adding them may be helpful.

Comment: Did they replace the dampers/shock absorbers?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Bolts might not be tight enough, bushings may be damaged, suspension pickup points might have been tweaked meaning that the suspension is no longer exactly where it was when it left the factory. Was the work done by a BMW dealer or authorized repair place, or by a small shop who works on everything? A non-BMW specialist may have gotten the job done, but not done properly.

Comment: Were any of the tyres replaced?